# Not incrementing variable in an anonymous callback function

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I've tried to use both `preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback` maybe in a wrong way. What I do wrong?

```
$str = '/admin/companies/{company}/projects/{project}/photos/{photo}/delete';
$pattern = '/({\w+})/';
$replacement = ['str_1', 'str_2', 'str_3'];

$i = 0;

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use ($i, $replacement) {
    return $replacement[$i++];
}, $str);
```

- Current Output:    `/admin/companies/str_1/projects/str_1/photos/str_1/delete`
- Expected Output: `/admin/companies/str_1/projects/str_2/photos/str_3/delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pass `$i` by reference, so it gets updated when you increment it with `$i++`:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use (&$i, $replacement) {
    return $replacement[$i++];
}, $str);
```

Notice the `&` before `$i`.